# calling fancybox for a thumbnail embedded with a Google Maps Infowindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox

I'd like to use fancybox on some thumbnails that I'd like to put in a Google Maps InfoWindow.

I am not sure it this is possible as I haven't seen this done but I should think it could be possible. I have the following:

```
$.each(value.items,function(k,mi){
  content_str+="<div class='info-window-item clearfix'><div class='info-window-image-box'>";
  content_str+="<a class='fancybox' href='" + mi.assets[0].full + "'><img  src='" + mi.assets[0].thumb +  "'></a></div>";
  content_str+="<div class='info-window-text'>";
  content_str+="<div class='my-info-window'>" + mi.header + "</div>";
  content_str+="<div class='info-window-detail'>" + mi.detail + "</div>";
  content_str+="</div>";
  content_str+="</div>";
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();    
});

infowindows[i]= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: content_str,
  maxWidth: 600
});
```

But this is not working. Any ideas how to set this up?

thx

Comment: I think you need to implement InfoBox content in the DOM node, instead of text, since fancybox cannot bind without an actual DIV tag defined explicitly.